# formula returning #NAME inside loop via selection from input box

Tags: excel, vba, loops, inputbox

I have a small macro and I would like that it does the following: the first input box ask the user to select a empty range where he wants to have in each cell of this range the debit/Credit… The 2nd input box ask the user to select a range of amounts (each amount in each cell of this range can be either negative or positive) . Then from these 2 selections, I would like that it returns “D” (debit) or “C” (credit) on each cell where it was selected the range of first input box. Unfortunately my macro does not work properly, indeed when I try to execute it, it returns me #NAME? (instead of “C” or “D” ) In each cell of the range selected via my first input box. For example on the picture below, I selected via my 1st input box the range K2:K5 (as an empty range)  and via my second input box the range C2:C5, after executing the macro, it returns me #NAME in each cell of range K2:K5.
Many Thanks in advance for your help.
Xavi
Please find my VBA code below:

```
Sub ReturncorrectCreditdebitcolumnbasedonselectioninputbox()
Dim c As Range
Dim WorkRng2 As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Please select the range where you want your Dedit/Credit", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
Set WorkRng2 = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng2 = Application.InputBox("Please select the range of amounts", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
For Each c In WorkRng
c.FormulaR1C1 = _
 "=If(WorkRng2.Value>0, ""D"",""C"")"
 Next c
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Excel will not know what `WorkRng2.Value` is [as part of a formula]. You might be able to replace it with `" & WorkRng.Address & "` ?

Comment: `"=If(" & WorkRng2.Value & " >0, ""D"",""C"")"`

Comment: Thank you CLR, thank you Comintern, I tried to insert your formula Comintern in the VBA code but when I run the macro, I get an error message : run time error 13, type mismatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't compare the value of multiple cells in one go so it will only work if `WorkRng2` is a single cell. Try the below, which is my best guess at what you are trying to do.

```
Sub ReturncorrectCreditdebitcolumnbasedonselectioninputbox()

Dim c As Long
Dim WorkRng2 As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range

Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Please select the range where you want your Dedit/Credit", , , Type:=8)
Set WorkRng2 = Application.InputBox("Please select the range of amounts", , , Type:=8)

If WorkRng.Count <> WorkRng2.Count Then
    MsgBox "Ranges must be same size"
Else
    For c = 1 To WorkRng.Count
        WorkRng.Cells(c).Formula = "=If(" & WorkRng2.Cells(c).Value & ">0, ""D"",""C"")"
    Next c
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot SJR for your explanation and your modification, it is solved my problem!